# How to access a grid item in detail template kendo ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a one-to-many relationship between person and address and I would like to display all the addresses in the grid detail. I know how to do this in a column, but it will look ugly.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Test")
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
    c.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    c.Bound(p => p.Addresses).Template(
        @<text>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var a in @item.Addresses)
                {
                    <li>@a.City</li>
                    <li>@a.Street</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </text>);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Groupable()
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:200px;" })
  )
```

I know I'm supposed to use a detail template, but I don't know how to access the correct person in the script.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">This 
     is where I need to iterate over the addresses
</script>
```

What's the best way of approaching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current template is driven each grid row for Addresses column. You can iterate Addresses list and include address information e.g. html list.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul>
        # for (var i = 0; i < data.Addresses.length; i++) { #
            <li>#=data.Addresses[i].City#</li>
        # } #
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Some explanation is always helpful.

Comment: Yeah, added some explanation for provided solution. @PiotrWolkowski

Comment: This works, you just forgot .length in the loop. Thanks!